# Import error after installing pip packagaes with sudo

Tags: python, django, pip

On Ubunutu 16.04 LTS, while trying to insatll packages using `pip install` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/graphviz-0.5.2.dist-info'
```

so I decided to use `sudo pip install` instead, which worked fine, until I tried importing said package to my Django project, I get the following import error:

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f749a55ee18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/nids/Automata/Automata/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^convert/', include('Convert.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/nids/Automata/Convert/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/nids/Automata/Convert/views.py", line 1, in <module>
    from graphviz import graphviz
ImportError: No module named 'graphviz'
```

how can I import those packages without encountering the import error? or how can I install them without sudo and without permission errors?

Comment: Use a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using virtual environment ? You should always have separate virtual env for every single project.

Installing everything in your main directory will create a chaos.

Install virtual environment, docs available here:

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Create your env with command:

`virtualenv -p python3.5 env`

activate your env (tell your console to use given env):

`source env/bin/activate`

and then you can install your packages with simple `pip install package_name`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python get-pip.py
```

To check the version and verify the installation:

```
pip -V
```